# Creating Windows Aero Wizards

Tags: c++, winapi, wizard, aero

I am new to Visual C++. I am trying to experiment the creation of a Windows Aero Wizard. I found [this reference on Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I cannot understand how to create it. Could anybody give me a good reference or tutorial please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is overly broad question. Look for code with `CreatePropertySheetPage` API usage. Windows SDK contains a few samples, e.g. under "\Samples\winui\shell\appplatform\aerowizards"; [Aero Wizards Sample (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.